# Adding ancestor selector to this javascript

Tags: javascript, selector, ancestor

Is there an easy way to add a bit about also setting the ancestor `li` tags to .active?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('toc').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}
window.onload = setActive;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. I don't get a full picture of what's going on from your question. From the looks of it you're grabbing an element with the id of "toc", so I'm guessing this toc contains `LI` elements as well as `A` elements. In which case you could use an asterisk in `getElementsByTagName`, which could be slower depending on how many other elements are there.

```
function setActive() {
  var href = window.location + ''
    , el = document.getElementById('toc')
    , a = el.getElementsByTagName('*')
    , i = 0
    , l = a.length
    , name;

  for (; i < l; i++) { 
    el = a[i];
    name = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (name === 'li' || (name === 'a' 
        && ~href.indexOf(el.href))) {
      el.className = 'active';
    }
  }
}
```

If you're asking for ancestral LI higher up in the document tree, this is what 
you would want:

```
function setActive() {
  var href = window.location + ''
    , el = document.getElementById('toc')
    , a = el.getElementsByTagName('a')
    , i = 0
    , l = a.length;

  // descendants
  for (; i < l; i++) { 
    if (~href.indexOf(a[i].href)) {
      a[i].className = 'active';
    }
  }

  // parents
  while (el = el.parentNode) {
    if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
      el.className = 'active';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Walk `element.parentNode` checking `tagName.toLowerCase() == "li"` to identify the parent `<li>`. Then set `className = "active"`.

```
var parent = aObj[i].parentNode;
while (parent && parent.tagName.toLowerCase() != "li")
    parent = parent.parentNode;
if (parent) parent.className = "active";
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it or anything, but I think this would work:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('toc').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
    var node = aObj[i];
    while(document != (node = node.parentNode)){
      if(node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li')
        node.className='active';
    }
  }
}
window.onload = setActive;
</script>
```